# Internet Explorer - weird shapes while browsing

Tags: internet-explorer

Basically, no matter which website I visit using IE, I can see those black/white shapes and they gone once I move mouse over them.

Wondering if anyone has an idea what could cause this?

[image: Gmail]

Also: http://imageshack.com/a/img674/3926/GaSSxT.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be due to your hardware. You could try switching to *Software Rendering* (Internet Options > Advanced > Software Rendering) and see if that resolves the issue.

[image]

Comment: As this happen on user computer, I'll have to wait until tomorrow (9am EST) to test this option, but from my perspective is a sign that nothing is lost :)
I'll keep you updated Jonathan and thanks for the QUICK help

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps Any improvement on the end-user experience after trying this?

Comment: IT DID THE TRICK! Thanks! Now, I'll have a look into her video card.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps You can run `dxdiag` from the *run* command to get additional information. Please consider accepting this answer for others who may be experiencing similar issues.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your help and attention. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use? It could be related to HTML5 or CSS3 rendering(Internet explorer 10 didn't support HTML5 and there are some issues with CSS3 on Internet explorer 8 or lower).

My suggestion: Don't user Internet explorer. EVER.

Comment: [IE 10 *does* support HTML 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673546(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yeah, thats why I said didn't... I had several issues with particular browser (unfortunately I had to use it...)

Comment: No wories Nick, the thing is: only one computer is showing this behavior with IE and with different sites (Gmail, IDAO, etc).

Comment: I work on the Internet Explorer team and would be more than happy to answer any questions you have. Regarding HTML 5 support though, it was there in IE 10. CSS3 support didn't ship with IE 8, but then again IE 8 is half a decade old.