# Internet Explorer artifacts when rendering

Tags: internet-explorer, rendering

I am getting some weird artifacts when rendering some elements in IE (9, 10, 11), they disappear when I invalidate the render (If I hover over an element to make its color change for example)

The artifacts are random but always appear on the same elements, they only occur when I have a second screen plugged in via HDMI so I am guessing it's some kind of a threading problem or a bad graphic card memory management..

I'm wondering why is this happening ?
Did any of you ever encoutered this bug ? Or is it just me ?

If you have, how did you fix it ? Do I need to reinstall IE ?

I don't think the problem comes from my code since there is no problem in other browsers (but if you think it could, just ask and I'll make it available so you can do some test)

Here are some examples with artifacts and without :

[image: artifact] [image: normal]

[image: artifact] [image: normal]

Comment: Do the artifacts remain when you switch the accelerated graphics to software rendering (and then restart the browser)? If not, then you should check the status of your video drivers, as there's likely an update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27259308/54680

Comment: Okay so i've made a few test and the bug only occurs when I have a second screen plugged in (with HDMI)

Comment: @Adri1du40 Did you check for driver updates, per Lance's suggestion?

Comment: I did and made the update, I also restarded my computer and reset the dpi of my screen to 96 but unfortunately the problem is still there.. and I think it's worse than before, now the artifacts are appearing even if I invalidate the first render.

I think it's an IE bug with multiple screens